# pip3 install error in AI Platform (Google Cloud Computing)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, setuptools, gcp-ai-platform-training

I've recently been trying to submit a training task to GCP's AI platform.

I successfully submitted the task to train my pytorch transformer model using the code below:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ${JOB_NAME} \
  --region=us-west1 \
  --module-name PipeLiner.PCM_main \
  --master-image-uri=gcr.io/cloud-ml-public/training/pytorch-cpu.1-4 \
  --package-path ../PipeLiner/ \
  --scale-tier=BASIC \
  --job-dir=${JOB_DIR} \
  -- \
  --config_file=/Users/mukundhmurthy/PycharmProjects/PipLinerTop/PipeLiner/PCM.yaml \
  --num-epochs=1 \
  --batch-size=2 \
  --learning-rate=0.00001 \
```

In the gcloud logging, I keep getting this error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pip3', 'install', '--user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall', '--no-deps', 'tape-pcm-trainer-0.1.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Thinking that this had something to do with my setup.py file, I checked my code there as well:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    req = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='tape-pcm-trainer',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=req,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='gcloud package for training TAPE on PCM dataset'
)
```

I also ran python setup.py sdist to make sure that the code could create the proper tar.gz file for my package.

I checked my python version and made sure to update my pip to the latest version. Any help on how to get past this bug would be great.

**Update**: This wasn't a gcloud problem. When I generated my requirements.txt file, some conda requirements snuck themselves into the file. Unfortunately, the gcloud training job logger doesn't show a stack trace beyond the run commands in the dockerfile, so it took a while to pinpoint this.

Comment: Could you firstly clarify if the training job ran successfully? Also, have you followed all the steps described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#before_you_begin) for packaging a training application? In addition, could you add `tape-pcm-trainer-0.1.tar.gz` to the --package flag as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/packaging-trainer#adding_custom_dependencies)?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Yes, I've been following the documentation you linked. The training job did not run successfully (last log says 'job failed'). I ran python setup.py sdist to create the tar.gz file and then added the --package flag as you mentioned, but that didn't work either (got the same exact pip3 install subprocess error).

Comment: How are you submitting the training job? Do you have enough permission to do so, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/access-control)? You need to have Training Admin or Developer.

Comment: How did you fix this? Facing the same problem.